# How to set focus to a particular cell in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code to focus to a particular cell in `DataGridView`.

```
private void dgOrderDetails_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
   if (dgOrderDetails.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "BILLINGMONT") {
     dgOrderDetails.Focus();
     dgOrderDetails.CurrentCell = dgOrderDetails[dgOrderDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1, dgOrderDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
   }
}
```

But my data grid cursor is not binding where I am expecting.

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = desiredCell;
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

Add your desired cell.

Comment: Upvoting for sportsmanship, your version will make it go into edit mode.

Comment: +1 for Explaination. it goes to editable into the current cell which i described. @JeremyThompson

Comment: Hi Coolprarun, I have tried this one. But my Datagridview cursor is not binding in the expected cell.please provide me some more Information.

Comment: HI User2738864, 
Is that cell is editable? Please make the ComboBox column property ReadOnly=False;

Answer (score 1):

```
datagridview.Focus();
datagridview.CurrentCell = datagridview.Rows[1].Cells[2];
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy Thompson, Thanks for your reply. I Have tried this one. But no luck. So please provide me some more Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to go to a cell after another, for example go to cells[5] after cells[1] in a current row.
I have this problem with datagridview but I found a good way for it:
in "CellLeave" event write this codes :

```
if (DatagridView.CurrentCell == DatagridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0])
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
```

I Go to cells[3] after cells[0]

I hope it Helps u

Answer (score -1):

```
grdUser.CurrentCell = grdUser.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];

grdUser.CurrentCell.Selected = true;

e.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: place this code to event & must write  e.cancel=true; because it prevent from further events.